# Which Let’s Encrypt clients support ACME v2 in the official Debian Buster repos?

Tags: debian, lets-encrypt, debian-buster

The ACME protocol version 1 is deprecated and will stop working with Let’s Encrypt in multiple steps from 2019 to 2021. See https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/end-of-life-plan-for-acmev1/88430

I’ve been using [acmetool](https://github.com/hlandau/acmetool) on Debian since *Stretch*. Unfortunately [version 0.0.62 in Debian’s current stable release *Buster*](https://packages.debian.org/buster/amd64/web/acmetool) doesn’t support ACME v2 yet.

So I am looking for alternatives. I really like the minimalistic design of `acmetool` and that it is idempotent. (This question is not about opinions on alternatives.)

Which clients from the official Debian Buster repo already support ACME v2?

Comment: The official client **certbot** supports v2 servers since [version 0.22](https://github.com/certbot/certbot/blob/master/certbot/CHANGELOG.md#0220---2018-03-07). Both Buster and Stretch (Updates) have a newer version.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite answering your question in that it is not in the official Debian buster stable repo, I found [acme.sh](https://acme.sh/) to be easier to work with and more transparent than certbot. And it already works with automatic DNS compliant providers like Cloudflare which I use.

My preferred option while we wait for the repo version of certbot to catch up.